# Find all distributions $T$ belonging to $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(x^2)T=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

My exercise is to find all distributions $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$, such that $(x^2)T=0$. On the lecture we solved the equation $xT=0$, where the solution where all distributions $T$, such that $T=C\delta.$

At that moment i think the solution of $(x^2)T=0$ is the same, but I'm not certain.
If You know better and can acknowledge that or give any hint, I'll be grateful.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Let $\psi \in C^\infty_c$ such that $\psi(x) = 1$ on $[-1,1]$. 
$x^2 T = 0$ means
$\forall \phi \in C^\infty_c,\langle x^2 T,\phi\rangle = 0$ so that $\langle T,\phi- \phi(0)\psi-x\phi'(0)  \psi \rangle = \langle x^2T,\frac{\phi- \phi(0)\psi-x\phi'(0)  \psi}{x^2} \rangle= 0$. Thus $\langle T,\phi\rangle = \phi(0) A + \phi'(0)B$ and $ T = A \delta- B \delta'$ where $A = \langle T,\psi\rangle, B = \langle T,x\psi\rangle$.

Comment: @reuns. You need some argument for $\frac{\phi- \phi(0)\psi-x\phi'(0)  \psi}{x^2} \in C_c^\infty$.

Comment: The only problem is at $0$, you can write the Taylor approximation of $\phi $ to find that of $\frac{\phi- \phi(0)\psi-x\phi'(0)  \psi}{x^2} $, otherwise there is $\int_0^1 \phi'(xt)dt = \int_0^x \phi'(u)d(u/x)= \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$ the LHS being clearly smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $S = xT$. Then the equation is $xS = 0$ which has solutions $S = C\delta$. Then you shall solve $xT = C\delta.$ Do you know any solution to $xT = \delta$? What are the solutions to the corresponding homogeneous equation? Add them.

Comment: What does "xT=0" mean here?

Comment: @Botond. What are you referring to? I haven't written $xT=0$.

Comment: Right, you've written $xS=0$, but I guess the name ($T$ or $S$) does not matter.

Comment: @Botond. The equation $xS=0$ means that the product of the function $x \mapsto x$ with the distribution $S$ results in the zero distribution.

Comment: sI found that solution to xT=delta is minus derivative of delta. So the general solution for xT=delta is A*(delta) - derivate of delta. So general solution of xT=C*delta is C*(A*delta - derivative of delta) = C1*delta -C2*(derivative of delta). Right?

Comment: @MaciejFicek. Please use MathJax when writing formulas, also in comments. It makes the text so much easier to read.

Comment: @MaciejFicek. But yes, the solutions to $xT = C\delta$ are $T=-C\delta' + D\delta,$ where $C$ and $D$ are constants.