# Distribution equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to solve $xT'+T = 0$ where $T$ is a distribution

I already know (it is asked in the previous point) that $(xT)'= T + xT'$

my thoughts : $ (xT)'(f) = - (xT)(f')$ and from this point I immediately think of $T$ equals the dirac measure at $0$ since  $\int xδ(f'(x)) = 0*f'(0) = 0$, or an arbitrary constant $c$ times the dirac measure at $0$

is it correct ?

Comment: any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any distribution supported at the origin will be a solution (so all derivatives of $\delta$). However these are not all, since any solution of $xT=constant$ will be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(xT)' = 0$ means $xT = c$, then let $S = pv(1/x)$,

$x  S = 1$ thus $x(T-c S) = 0$ which [means](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234687/find-all-distributions-t-belonging-to-mathcald-mathbbr-such-that-x?noredirect=1#comment6654300_3234687) $T-c S = b \delta$